# Calcular posicion con distancia y puntos de referencia

Tags: java, matemáticas

Tengo un aparato, llamémosle origen, que manda una señal y le llegan a otras maquinas, llamémosle satélites. De cada satélite yo conozco su posición y la distancia del origen.

Ejemplo:

```
Posición satélite 1: [-500, -200]
Posición satélite 2: [100, -100]
Posición satélite 3: [500, 100]
```

Y la distancia de cada uno sería:

```
Distancia satélite 1: 100.0
Distancia satélite 2: 115.5
Distancia satélite 3: 142.7
```

Supuestamente el resultado sería:

```
x: -100.0
y: 75.5
```

Como calculo las coordenadas del origen? O como se llama este tipo de problemas?
Principalmente necesito buscar, tal vez, una librería en java para resolver este tipo de problemas.

Había visto esta: https://github.com/lemmingapex/Trilateration
Pero el resultado que me arroja es un poco distinto a lo que esperaba, por eso no sé si es la librería adecuada a mi problema o si el resultado que me dieron estaba mal.

Perdón si este es un ejercicio muy bobo, hace años terminé la escuela y honestamente no me acuerdo mucho de matemática.

De paso alguien conoce alguna libreria en java que pueda resolver

Con la librería de https://github.com/lemmingapex/Trilateration intenté esto:

```
double[][] positions = new double[][] { { -500.0, -200.0 }, { 100.0, -100.0 }, { 500.0, 100 } };

NonLinearLeastSquaresSolver solver = new NonLinearLeastSquaresSolver(new TrilaterationFunction(positions, distances), new LevenbergMarquardtOptimizer());
Optimum optimum = solver.solve();
    
double[] centroid = optimum.getPoint().toArray();
```

Y el resultado que me tiene centroid  es [-58.315252587138595, -69.55141837312165], no [-100, 75.5]

El tema es que no sé si estoy usando la función correcta o si me pasaron mal la respuesta.

Comment: Pon lo q has intentado para que se te pueda ayudar

Comment: @Japv, tenes razón. Ahí edité. Gracias

Comment: El tipo de problema se llama triangulación, es justamente lo que hacen los gps para calcular la ubicación. Es por eso que necesitas 3 o más satélites para poder hacer el cálculo. Acá hay informacion sobre eso https://acolita.com/como-funcionan-los-dispositivos-gps-trilateracion-vs-triangulacion/#:~:text=A%20medida%20que%20los%20sat%C3%A9lites,GPS%20no%20implica%20ning%C3%BAn%20%C3%A1ngulo.

Comment: @Brett, para eso tiene q haber formulas, ese es un problema matematico mas que de programacion

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema de geometría analítica, te dejo unos links que te pueden ayudar.
Lo primero que tiene que hacer es hallar la ecuacion de la resta de las circunferencias que está en el siguiente link de geogebra (solo tendria que crear algunas variables con nombre sin ningún sentido pero bueno):

[link de geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/jzfe2zhn)

Después al tener la funcion f(x) de geogebra tiene que igualarla a 0 y aplicar bhaskara, despues sustituir x en la funcion para tener y. si la parte de la raiz cuadrada es negativa, hay dos opciones: que la circunferencia este dentro de la otra circunferencia o que esté muy lejos.

Al saber si intersecciona o no y en que valores de x e y, ahora tocaría introducir la otra circunferencia y calcular las distancias de todos los puntos entre sí y posiblemente el origen esté en el punto con la distancia tendiendo a 0 o que sea menor al error permitido.

Otra opción es medir la distancia directamente entre los dos puntos A y B aplicando bhaskara que me parece mejor y comparar esa distancia con la de los datos iniciales.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BhsWxtGDog